# Maven can't compile, but Eclipse shows no errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jersey

Given the following structure:

```
root (pom)
  + child (pom)
      + webapp (war)
```

**Root** has some dependencies in dependencyManagement (to specify a version for child) and child also has dependencyManagement (to specify a version for webapp). **Root** also has a dependency in its management section for **Jersey**:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.21</version>
  </dependency>
```

**Webapp** actually uses this dependency in its regular dependencies section:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Eclipse shows no compilation errors at all and I use some classes from the package org.glassfish.jersey.server. When I look in Eclipse under "Libraries -> Maven Dependencies" it shows the correct libraries, including jersey-server-2.21.jar.

However, when I run mvn clean install, I get compilation errors referring to package org.glassfish.jersey.server. I've tried cleaning my project, but the problem persist. It's likely to do with dependencyManagement, but I'm not sure how. Are provided dependencies just doomed with dependencyManagement?

Comment: please paste stacktrace

Comment: Can you please add full stacktrace? Also  `mvn` build not successful?

Comment: I can't paste the stacktrace, but I enabled some debugging and saw the required library not included in the classpath.

Comment: Without exact stacktrace its hard to tell you Solution are you using some repository to download jar or maven default repository?

Comment: Try to clean your local maven repo. Maybe there are some old artifacts that make Eclipse work.

Comment: have you resolved this issue??